# ¿Como puedo crear un gif desde la terminal de linux?

Tags: bash, shell, gif

Me encontre con la necesidad de crear un animado con un gif y luego de buscar en diferentes sitios encontre un comando que es muy bueno sin necesitar instalar herramientas solo con la ternimal de linux.

Answer (score 2):

Este es un comando basico solo abre la terminal y ejecuta esto:

```
~$ convert -delay 25 1.png 2.png 3.png 4.png 5.png 6.png 7.png 8.png 9.png 10.png -loop 0 animacion.gif
```

Lo comparto para cualquiera que tenga el interes de usarlo o compartir otras formas para crear gif.